# Minimax Algorithm: Does order of turns matter?

Tags: artificial-intelligence, minimax, alpha-beta-pruning

I am currently doing the Pacman projects from Berkley's Intro to AI course. I was wondering if the order of minimizer/maximizer layers is crucial in a purely team adversarial game.

Two teams compete against each other. Each team has two players. Will there be any significant advantage in ordering the layers?

My turn (maximizer)

My teammate's turn (maximizer)

Opponent #1 (minimizer)

Opponent #2 (minimizer)

or

My turn (maximizer)

Opponent #1 (minimizer)

My teammate's turn (maximizer)

Opponent #2 (minimizer)

etc.

Thank you!